# How can I split delimited strings into specific individual cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following nodes:

[image]

**Expected output:**

[image]

My current steps to get this are:

1. Delimit by "/"
2. Sort
3. Conditionally format some cells. I'm trying to make the cells blank by doing A2=A1 and setting the font color to white. However this is not working.

[image]

How can I do that using VBA? I am told that this would probably require VBA.
The trick is keeping only one of the parent nodes per line.

Comment: Can you post an example of what the expected output should be?

Comment: @Miguel, Hi Miguel, the expected output is in the 2nd picture. sry ill make that more clear.

Comment: Ok now makes sense, so are you just trying to remove DUPS? by column? or do you really want to make the font a white color so that is not visible?

Comment: @Miguel , remove dups. But thought white colour might be a workaround.

Comment: I wouldn't go this route to start with but if you do, abandon the white font and set teh cell number format to `;;;`.

Comment: If all you are trying to do is remove dups by column why not just use the "Remove duplicates" in the DATA tab? under your ribbon, Sorry, maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @miguel, I tried. So if I remove dups from the full set, data goes missing, and if i do it column by column, it isnt much of a tree structure. maybe Ill post a pic of this.

Comment: @ jonnyboi I see what you mean now. give me a few mins, I can wip this up pretty fast.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but it gets the job done. This will loop through columns A-F rows 1-12 and select the value for each cell find that occurrence and delete the second occurrence not the first. This should do the trick.

```
Sub findItemInColumns()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For r = 1 To 12
            For c = 1 To 6
                RemoveDups .Cells(r, c).Value
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub RemoveDups(ByVal somevalueToFindAndRemove As String)

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range



    listOfValues = Array(somevalueToFindAndRemove)

    If Trim(somevalueToFindAndRemove) <> "" Then
        With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AK")

            For i = LBound(listOfValues) To UBound(listOfValues)

                Set Rng = .Find(What:=listOfValues(i), _
                                After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
                If Not Rng Is Nothing Then 
                    FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                    Do
                        Application.Goto Rng, True    
                        If Rng.Address <> FirstAddress Then Rng.Value = ""
                        Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                    Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Ever heard of this wonderful thing called *indentation*? Also, this code clearly wants an inner loop from 1 to 6. Lazy code like this is error-prone, as evidenced by the copy-pasta error in the last loop ("gets the job done" - did you test it?). And `Call` is completely redundant, too.

Comment: :-) Thanks Mat, I truly love purist like you. As I said, this is quick and dirty, please read the post above. Is truly folks like you, the make the world a better place by offering criticism and not value. Thanks again for the wonderful comment.

Comment: For Christ's sake... here, is that enough "value" for you? FWIW I've contributed 388 answers in the VBA tag (and another 175 over on CR.SE), I believe I'm providing "value" more than just criticism. If you're going to give "here try this" code-dump answers, at least have the decency of making them working code.

Comment: Once again Mat, thank you for your effort and for fixing my answer. I'll admit that the code was not optimize but it did work on my machine when I tested it. It seems like your main moderator around here, I'm not trying to cramp your style. I'm deeply humbled and forgive my answer,  I would deleted if I could. I was simply trying to get him help as fast as possible.(sorry about that)

Comment: FWIW, "quick and dirty" answers tend to come back later as more "why does this code that half an hour to run", or "how do I combine these 6 copied and pasted loops", or any number of other things.  If you answer questions using bad coding practices just to "help as fast as possible", you aren't doing ***anyone*** a favor - you're promoting using bad coding practices.

Comment: Thanks so much Miguel and Mat. Currently running this, takes awhile as I am applying it to 40k rows.  Would updating disabling screen updating make this faster?

Comment: Found somewhat of a problem, seems to be many rows skipped in between nodes(blank rows). a F5, blank removal doesnt work as that does all blanks. Should be one value per line.

Answer (score 1):

Try with formulas (in new sheet or column) like

```
X2     =IF(A2=A1,"",A2)
X3     =IF(A3=A2,"",A3)
X4     =IF(A4=A3,"",A4)
```

etc..

For column A